# Serverless framework does not deploy internal folders to aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I have a folder structure for lambda as follows created using

serverless create --template aws-python --path base_folder

base_folder
 - serverless.yml
 - src
    - src/handler.py
    - src/another_folder
        - src/another_folder/file.json

When I run serverless deploy, I do not see the another_folder in the lambda management console on aws.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to specify this particular folder inside `serverless.yml` if it's not specified or referenced from your code files:

```
service: your_project_name
# your serverless code...
package:
  include:
    src/another_folder/**
# more serverless code...
```

See the docs on serverless packaging [here](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/packaging/).

Thanks @dege for pointing out I missed the `/**` to note the contents of the actual folder

Comment: I have already tried this. This does not work for me. Also putting this makes not difference at all, with 'serverless deploy' saying 'Service files not changed. Skipping deployment...'

Comment: Could you post your `serverless.yml` contents?

Comment: you should have the /** to include the content of the folder

Comment: Actually i found out that the internal folders are getting deployed. It's the inline code editor of aws lambda console that does not reflect those folders.

Comment: That would be the Cloud9 editor. It was only released last week so there's bound to be issues there. I've encountered a few myself. These folders should be shown.

Comment: I still getting this problem, wants to include markdown files into a folder named folders and I did find any solution, with ```sls offline``` I can retrieve the files in this folder, but with aws deploy, crashes.